# Passportjs authentication with local and twitter strategies

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to link twitter with existing logged in user session and I have configured passport as below for authentication using local and twitter strategies

```js
//Configure passport to use Twitter Authentication strategy
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/twitter/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    // Although the req is being passed pack to my callback, the below function is not being executed at all
    if (!req.user) {
      console.log("Not already authenticated using local strategy")
    } else {
      console.log("Already Authenticated using local strategy, link twitter")
    }
  }
));

// Configure passport for local auth
passport.use(new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email_addr',
}, User.authenticate()));


passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

/ Link Twitter
app.get('/auth/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'));


app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated) {
    res.redirect("/")
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login")
  }
})
```

Issue #1: Everything works well. However, the embedded function below is not being executed for me to link the twitter acct before the callback even though req is being passed back to callback

```js
function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  // Although the req is being passed pack to my callback, the below function is not being executed at all, with no error message

  if (!req.user) {
    console.log("Not already authenticated using local strategy")
  } else {
    console.log("Already Authenticated using local strategy")
  }
}
```

Issue #2: Is there a way to pass the returned twitter profile back to callback in addition to the req? so as to be able to log it to console on /auth/twitter/callback while retaining the authenticated user's local session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Apparently, the embedded function while configuring passport for twitter strategy will only be executed if the authentication is successful and failure can be handled on the callback.

```js
//Configure passport to use Twitter Authentication strategy
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/twitter/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    //can perform any function in here as it will only be executed on successful Auth
  }
));
// Configure passport for local auth
passport.use(new localStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email_addr',
}, User.authenticate()));


passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Link Twitter
app.get('/auth/twitter',
  passport.authenticate('twitter'));

app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    //on successful auth 
    res.redirect('/home');
  });
```